# Updating page layout of Einstein Field Recommendation component

Tags: service-cloud-console, einstein

I am currently learning about **Einstein for Service** from [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/service_einstein) and [SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.einstein_service_intro.htm&type=5). It has suite of tools to fuel the service cloud with AI capabilities.  [Einstein's Prediction in Case Classification app](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cc_service_field_considerations.htm&type=5). This is part of  tools suite.

**Einstein Classification** is one of the tools available in this suite, and it has two modes:

1. Case Classification - Predict fields based confidence threshold of past data.
2. Case Wrap-up - Predict fields on case closure from **Chat** transcripts data.

#### Problem statement

Working on the Case classification App, I am having an issue with Checkbox field. I have setup the Einstein data model as shown below. "IsVisibleInSelfSevice" is checkbox type field and it is visible and editable to all profiles.

[image]

Now, I am not seeing the checkbox field in the Einstein Field Prediction component on the Page Layout. As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cc_service_field_considerations.htm&type=5)

> - Make sure that the fields you choose are
>   added to your console case page layout. Agents can’t see predictions
>   for a field that isn't included in the layout.

The field is there on the case page layout and I can edit it as well but just don't see it on Einstein field prediction component.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once, I am pleased to say that I got a resolution for a **technical case** from Salesforce. :D

### Updating layout of Einstein Field Prediction Component

*Below solution assumes that the Einstein Prediction model is already build and activated. For details on that please follow the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/service_case_class/turn-on-einstein-case-classification)*

1. Open the Lightning App Builder > Case Page Layout
2. Drop or select the [Einstein Field Recommendation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cc_service_lex_setup.htm&type=5) component on the page layout.
3. Under the **Update Action**, select an existing Update Action on Case object. If no Update Action is present then create a New one. Fields mentioned in the update action will be displayed in the Field Recommendation component.
   [image]
4. Goto Setup > Case > Buttons, Links, and Actions and select the action mentioned in Step 3.
5. Press the "Edit Layout" button
6. Add/Remove field which you would like the Einstein AI to Predict.